# How to close an opened folder in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I love VSCode. But I can't find a way to close an opened folder. It seems that you can only open one folder at a time. And the only way to close it is to close the whole program?

Am I missing something?

Comment: You can open another folder instead.

Comment: You can now do `File -> Close Folder [Ctrl+K F]`, you should change the accepted answer @skyline75489

Comment: For seriously puzzled inquirers, you must _release_ the control key before pressing F.  This isn't the way any other application works on windows, that I can tell.

Comment: @dudeNumber4 - that was clutch!

Comment: The fact that we had to come to StackOverflow to figure out how to do this, shows how incredibly badly intuitive the VSCode IDE is. They really need to work on making it better. I've mentioned this to them via GitHub issues too.

Answer (score 250, accepted):

The command to close the currently opened folder can be found from `File` -> `Close Folder`.

You can also use the shortcut:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd>

(press and hold `Ctrl`, then press and release `K`, then release `Ctrl`, and then press `F`)

And on a Mac:

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd>

Comment: This close every opened folder though. What if I want to only close one folder?

Comment: now a good thing in VS Code is --> they have mentioned the available keyboard shortcuts in right side of every command which pops using  **CTRL+P**

Comment: Note that the command it Ctrl + K release the keys, then F. I was pressing it it as Ctrl + K + F and it wasn't working, but there is a hint at what's doing in the bottom left.

Comment: This just closes the window for me... ie it closes every opened folder and not just the one selected

Comment: My workflow is: invoke integrated terminal and prompt `code path/to/newProjectFolder`
so there is no need to explicitly close the currently opened folder you're not interesting to work on.

Comment: It works but does more than what it's supposed to. This also closes all opened files even if the files aren't even part of the folder we wish to close

Answer (score 24):

With the 0.3.0 update we added a new command to close a folder. You can find it under the `File` menu.

Comment: What is the complete command name ? is there complete documentation of all the commands available?

Comment: I didn't find it. Sure the File: directive is implemented but there is no such a thing as File: close folder or something like this at the moment.

Comment: That's only available through the menu. Doesn't appaear in the Palette commands...

Answer (score 19):

VSCode doesn't have an explicit close folder gesture yet. You can either select `File > Open Folder` in a open windows of VSCode or select `File > New Window` and in there `File > Open`. Having multiple open folders inside a single window isn't supported.

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer anymore. As stated on other answers, we can now close a folder using the menu `File` → `Close Folder` or the shortcut `Ctrl`+`K` `F`.

Answer (score 10):

As VS Code remembers the last session when opened, you can:

1. open New Window (Ctrl+Shift+N) - this will open new VS Code with no project folders opened,
2. close the old window (with opened project folder),
3. close the new one.

Next time you run VS Code, it should look like the last window you closed and thus without any folders opened.

Note that this process closes ALL opened folders.

Answer (score 3):

For all what you have in your mind for "[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)" use simply "[Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)" throught

> menu: VS Code / View / Command Palette...
>
> keyboard: <kbd>CMD / CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

and then you can find all by text.

> text: Close All Editors
>
> keyboard: <kbd>CMD / CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

Also you can find and redefine all "[Key Bindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)" here

> menu: VS Code / Code / Preferences / Keyboard Shortcuts
>
> keyboard: <kbd>CMD / CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

Comment: this does not answer the question at all. "Close all editors" does not close the folder. The folder is still there. In fact, as of Dec 2023, there is no command palette item for "close folder"; File -> Close folder is the only way.

Comment: @xdavidliu you have right - in 2019 didn't catch that

Answer (score 2):

if open a folder in workspace ( File > Add Folder to Workspace ) you can close folder with [ right click on folder name > remove folder from workspace ] but if you open folder from (file > open folder) you can close with  [File > Close Folder]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`CTRL + SHIFT + P` then "Collapse Folders in Explorer"

[image]